Using Reverb to display status messages
I'm trying to use Reverb to display updates after a form submission.  In my blade file with the form, I added the following code.
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(window.Echo); // Check if Echo is defined
            // Listening for the CommandExecuted event
            window.Echo.channel('p-status')
                .listen('TerminusCommandExecuted', (event) => {
                    console.log("event.message"); // Output the message to console
            });
        }, 200);

And my event file

<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class TerminusCommandExecuted implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message; // Property to hold the message

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param string $message
     */
    public function __construct(string $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message; // Assign the message to the property
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): Channel
    {
        // Return a single Channel instance instead of an array
        return new Channel('p-status'); // Correctly returning a Channel instance
    }
}

And in my job file that processes the form, I added the following
use App\Events\TerminusCommandExecuted;
event(new TerminusCommandExecuted($message));

Things that work.
From the blade file
console.log(window.Echo.channel('pantheon-status') or just window.Echo
Using Tinker
new App\Events\TerminusCommandExecuted('Test message');
However window.Echo.channel('p-status').listen never fires.  This is local development. I appreciate the help.
